# Running Ubuntu on xbox 360, possible to play pc games?

Tags: games

I'm considering throwing ubuntu onto my xbox 360, but wanted to know if it'd be able to handle a single game, League of Legends.

I'm guessing no, not because the hardware isn't capable, but because there are no drivers good enough for the graphics needed.  Curious though as to if it's possible as I currently am unable to play it on this pc (too outdated).

Answer (score 2):

Xbox 360 is a tri-core and has 512MB of GDDR3 clocked at 700MHz. It is shared between the CPU and GPU via unified memory architecture It doesn't have to run a desktop environment or even an X server or many hardware drivers.

The GPU its self is called a Xenos. The GPU package contains two separate silicon dies, each on a 90 nm chip with a clock speed of 500 MHz; the GPU proper and a 10 MB eDRAM daughter-die. Thanks to the daughter die, the Xenos can do 4x FSAA, z-buffering, and alpha blending with no appreciable performance penalty on the GPU.

This is how it is able to play games the way it does.

So if you load the xbox up with Ubuntu, an X Server and a DE, there isn't going to be enough of that 512MB to run a game on a system that isn't using drivers designed for the hardware.

So I am afraid you have guessed right, it is a no go on the Xbox. You will have to invest on some upgrade for your machine. And even if you do, you will still have to run the games via wine, which may cause problems within its self.

Comment: THat's a lot of amazing detail

Comment: What can I say, I'm an XBox man! lol

Answer (score 1):

You basically guessed right: it won't work. League of Legends doesn't even *have* a native Linux client. So, you'd basically be trying to emulate something on a platform that's not even supported by the hardware to begin with.

The only "real" hack is [Free60](http://www.free60.org/wiki/Main_Page) but it looks dormant. I'd just drop the $400 on a laptop that can play it. It really doesn't take much.

Comment: Oh I have a computer that can play it, I was just curious as to if I could force the xbox to as well...

Comment: You'd be hard pressed to do so. As it is, Wine (which is what you'd need to run it on Linux) is very picky with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to develop a Framebuffer driver to handle the 3D and get rid of the X11 overhead. You could then make 3D games that boot and run directly from the CLI/Boot Init. Not an easy task but it is possible if someone is interested in doing it. It's definitely not a 5 minute or 5 day project. You'd need to get deep into MESA and the Linux Framebuffer graphics stack. But people have done similar projects. This Presentation on Youtube talks about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1oXByIJcHU&ab_channel=FOSDEM